# Audio stops working after a few minutes

Tags: boot, audio, drivers, reboot

I swapped my previous PSU since it had failed. I've been having this issue since then. I boot up the computer, start watching a video, after a few minutes the audio goes off completely and I start hearing that whizzing noise, though it's very quiet. Now, if I reboot the computer it starts working for a few minutes and goes off again. During that time the sound quality is noticeably bad.

I've tried reinstalling the audio driver. Didn't help.
Formatted the computer entirely, installed drivers. Didn't help.
Updated GPU driver just in case, didn't help.
Tried other audio devices, didn't help.
I also made sure I was using the correct rear port.
Updated BIOS, still not workin

6600k
MSI Z170M Mortar
RX 480 8gb
16GB RAM
Antec HCG-620 PSU
Windows 10 64-bit

This looks like a motherboard issue, though I'm not sure what to do about it. I really am desperate at this point. Any help would be appreciated.